# Excel - Formula to add one number to another, but remain unchanged if one number is deleted

Tags: excel, if-statement, running-count

in excel I want to record a monthly total of items distributed and an all-time total. At the start of a new month, the monthly totals reset back to 0, but I want the all-time total to remain unchanged. This all-time number should only increase over time.
The spreadsheet may be used through a browser or teams as well as the desktop app, so if I can avoid macros that would be ideal.
Can a cell be used like a container or variable?

| Monthly total | Var | All time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | =IF(A2<>0,A2,"") | =B2 |

I'm trying an if statement, but I'm not sure if a 'do nothing' option is available.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Best would be using google-sheet. Then use `QUERY()` function. For desktop excel use LAMBDA() functions. Post few sample data and desired output.

Comment: Hi Harun24hr,

Start of month 1
|Item |Monthly Total | |Item |Total to date |
|-------|---------------| |-------|---------------| 
|A |0  | |A |0  | 
|B |0  | |B |0  | 
|C |0  | |C |0  | 

End of month 1
|Item |Monthly Total | |Item |Total to date |
|-------|---------------| |-------|---------------|
|A |11  | |A |11  |
|B |6  | |B |6  |
|C |3  | |C |3  |

At the start of a new month, the monthly totals are reset to 0. The totals to date should not reset, but stay as they are, and increment as the month totals increment throughout the month.

Comment: Start of month 2
|Item |Monthly Total | |Item |Total to date |
|-------|---------------| |-------|---------------| 
|A |0  | |A |11  | 
|B |0  | |B |6  | 
|C |0  | |C |3  | 

End of month 2
|Item |Monthly Total | |Item |Total to date |
|-------|---------------| |-------|---------------|
|A |10  | |A |21  |
|B |10  | |B |16  |
|C |10  | |C |13  |

I hope this helps, thanks.

Comment: The tables haven't formatted as tables, apologies.